# SSH and sudo over a pseudo-tty terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, ansible

I am trying to overcome some limitations in our environment to write up an authorized SSH file for passwordless ssh keys.

I am requiring to perform an ssh as a to a target system, and then run a "`sudo su -` , and then update the service account authorized_keys with a key"

This eventually has to go onto my ansible scripts.

I am using "`ssh -t user@target` "`sudo su - service-user`" - which actually successfully gets me into a shell for service-user. But I am not able to figure out a way to pass along the file modify commands with the above.

Any tips or alternative options?

Note: I need to use "`ssh -t`" option as the requiretty is not set on target systems.

Cheers!

Comment: Just a side note, doing `sudo su - service-user` is a bit overkill: it runs the `su` command as root just to drop down again to a different user. If you want an interactive session, you can get the same effect with `sudo -iu service-user`. This may allow you to tighten up the sudoers file a bit too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to overwrite service-user's authorized_keys file with a completely new version, you could do something like this:

```
cat master_authorized_keys |
    ssh -t user@target \
        "sudo -u service-user tee ~/.ssh/authorized_keys >/dev/null"
```

I don't know if the `-t` there is really necessary, but maybe it is in your environment.

Comment: Yep had figured out the same as above after much trial and error. Cheers!